# Can I set the two parameters of setInterval from two other functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, setinterval

Can I set the two parameters of setInterval from two other functions in javascript?

Instead of this...

```
myVar = setInterval(function1, 8000);
```

I'd like to do this... where function2 sets the milliseconds.

```
myVar = setInterval(function1, function2);
```

The below example is what I would like to do. This does not work. Returns a "stuttering" on the page.

Example #1
https://thehighcountrydiscgolfclub.com/friends/jiesen/example01.html

Any guidance is appreciated. 
Even if it's a better way to ask this question...

Here's the html for the radio-group, select-menu and button.

```
<input type="radio" value="chime-04" name="rad" onclick="soundSelect(this.value);" checked="checked">Chime
<input type="radio" value="bell-04" name="rad" onclick="soundSelect(this.value);">Bell
<input type="radio" value="bleep-04" name="rad" onclick="soundSelect(this.value);">Bleep
<br>
<audio id="audio">
    <source src="" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="" type="audio/wav">
    <source src="chime-04.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" id="sound">
</audio>
<br>
<select id="space">
    <option value="4000">0:04 Seconds</option>
    <option value="6000">0:06 Seconds</option>
    <option value="8000">0:08 Seconds</option>        
</select>
<br>
<button type="button" id="toggle" onclick="runSoundInterval()">Play / Pause</button>


function soundSelect(val){
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    var aud = document.getElementById("sound");
    aud.src=val+".mp3";
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
}
function intervalSelect(val){
    var space = document.getElementById("space");
    var value = space.options[space.selectedIndex].value;
}
function runSoundInterval() {
    myVar = setInterval(soundSelect, intervalSelect);
}
```

Here I tried condensing the three functions into just one. I like it. Radio buttons play sound and alerts the correct selected select menu value but does not repeat sound. Button only returns the alert, but no sound and no repeat. Notice that I'm trying to pull the setInterval milliseconds from "value". Added the Alert to prove that the correct value is being chosen from the select menu. The alert is just a test and will need to be removed in the future. Doesn't completely work.

Example #2
https://thehighcountrydiscgolfclub.com/friends/jiesen/example02.html

```
function soundSelect(val){
var space = document.getElementById("space");
    var value = space.options[space.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(value);
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    var aud = document.getElementById("sound");
    aud.src=val+".mp3";
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
}
window.setInterval(soundSelect, value);
```

Comment: The second argument is supposed to be a number. It can be any expression that returns a number, including a function *call*, but not a function *reference*. But even if you called your `intervalSelect()` function it doesn't return a value, or indeed do anything useful given it just assigns values to *local* variables that then aren't used. As an aside, you can get the current value of your select element with `space.value`, no need to go via the `.options` collection.

Comment: @nnnnnn— IIRC, the *selectedIndex* route was required for some ancient version of Netscape Navigator, amazing how such memes persist.

Comment: @RobG - Yeah, I remember doing it in IE back at about version 4.

Answer (score 3):

If function2 returns the seconds, simply use its return value:

```
myVar = setInterval(function1, function2());
```

Comment: That apostrophe must have really pissed you off.